# What does (stuct sockadrr*)&servaddr mean?

Tags: c, sockets

I 've encountered this piece of code:

```
(stuct sockadrr*)&servaddr
```

What does that mean? You cast the struct somehow to `servaddr`?

I'm just trying to figure out the syntax of this code and the meaning of it in C.

Comment: The way you worded your question suggests that you are completely unfamiliar with the syntax and semantics of casting in C as well as other basic C syntax. I'd suggest you read some book on C instead of trying to learn the language by asking narrow-scoped questions on forums.

Answer (score 3):

> You cast the struct somehow to servaddr?

No, the other way round, you cast the address of `servaddr` to a pointer to `struct sockaddr`.

If `servaddr` has type `foo`, `&servaddr` is a `foo*`, a pointer to `foo`. If you call a function that expects a pointer to `struct sockaddr`, you need to cast it - if the types are compatible, so that passing a `foo*` as a `struct sockaddr*` works.

Comment: Thanks.. another thing i would like to ask is that i am using sockaddr_in..so the logical thing is to use (struct sockaddr_in *)&serveraddr right? and another thing why do we have to put the keyword struct inside the paretheses? Not putting it would be wrong?

Comment: Yes, casting to `struct sockaddr_in*` would then be the right thing (assuming, to say it once more, that the types are compatible [for the user, not necessarily in the standard sense of compatible types]). You need the `struct` because in C there is no implicit `typedef struct sometag { .. } sometag;` like in C++. If you provide a typedef (or the header provides one), you can use the typedef name instead of `struct tag`.

Answer (score 2):

Various socket functions are declared to take as a parameter a generic network address, you cast the address of a specific network address struct (e.g. `sockaddr_in`) in order to pass it as a parameter to the function.